# Connect to the text console of a running VM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have a running VM with vnc disabled. This is the command running it:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -name scratch -S -machine pc-i440fx-trusty,accel=kvm,usb=off -m 512 -realtime mlock=off -smp 1,sockets=1,cores=1,threads=1 -uuid a735aa8d-8805-429a-d8e1-e4fe17453210 -nographic -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/scratch.monitor,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc -no-reboot -boot strict=on -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x1.0x2 -drive file=/tmp/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64-AA0J.img,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=raw -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=2 -drive file=/tmp/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.copy.iso,if=none,id=drive-ide0-1-0,readonly=on,format=raw -device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-1-0,id=ide0-1-0,bootindex=1 -netdev tap,fd=24,id=hostnet0,vhost=on,vhostfd=25 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=00:00:00:00:00:07,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4
```

It has been started without graphic console, so that `virt-viewer` will not connect. How can I connect to the text console? Is there a program for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `virsh console yourservername` work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works. But I do not understand why, since I am not using virsh to manage this particular VM.

Comment: I guess it uses `libvirt` under the hood :)

Comment: it definitely uses libvirt. the command provided was probably extracted from `ps`  post-factum.

Comment: @dyasny: You got me! :) Yes, I am creating the VM with `virt-install`, which probably uses libvirt.

Comment: anything `virt-*` is indeed part of libvirt